# Why is the composite map defined on the given domain in the definition of a smooth map between manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is a definition from the book Introduction to manifolds by Tu (Page 61 definition 6.5)

[image]

My question is related to the highlighted part. Why is the highlighted portion the domain of the composition? Is it part of the definition or does it naturally follow somehow?

Comment: Hint: Note that $F(U)$ does not have to be a subset of $V$

Comment: That's true. But I still don't get it. I don't know what I am missing here. Could you please give some more details?

Comment: The author restricts $F$ to $F^{-1}(V) \cap U$ to get a function, which maps a subregion of the $\phi$-chart to a subregion of the $\psi$-chart. Only then it makes sense to "read F in local charts"! Try drawing a picture of the situation.

Comment: But why isn't U enough? Why do we need to restrict it? I am sorry but I am unable to understand this. Please bear with me.

Comment: If you just restrict $F$ to $U$ and there exists an $x \in U$ such that $F(x) \not\in V$. Then $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ is not defined for $\phi(x)$.

Comment: I get it now.Thanks a lot !